# Can I have a php site on subdirectory of Wordpress?

Tags: php, directory

I have a Wordpress site (www.example.com) and I need to have a php site on subdirectory(www.example.com/shop).
I was wondering is it possible or not?

Comment: why not to simply try? theoretically there is no problem, but it might not work for your specific needs, so the best way to know, is to try

Comment: I want to try, but I don't have any Idea what should I do.

Comment: Than maybe you should edit your question and ask explicitly about what is it that you are having trouble with.

Answer (score 1):

**Technically, it's possible.** And it works.

You could have a PHP site on a sub-directory like `example.com/shop`.

But, a better practice is to host that PHP site on a sub-domain like `shop.example.com`. It helps in better maintenance and provides a better structure for organizing the site.

On a `Nginx` server, your config should be something like:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name shop.example.com;

    root /var/www/html/shop;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ \.php$ {
                include fastcgi.conf;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;

        }
    }
```

If you still insist on having your `shop` at `example.com/shop`, no extra configuration is necessary. Your pre-installed WordPress setup is all. It would work seamlessly. But, keep in mind that `shop` files must be kept inside a folder called `shop` in your home directory.